# How to write the ValueJoiner when joining two Kafka Streams defined using Avro Schemas?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I am building an ecommerce application, where I am currently dealing with two data feeds: order executions, and broken sales. A broken sale would be an invalid execution, for a variety of reasons. A broken sale would have the same order ref number as the order, so the join is on order ref # and line item #.

Currently, I have two topics - `orders`, and `broken`. Both have been defined using Avro Schemas, and built using SpecificRecord. The key is `OrderReferenceNumber`.

Fields for `orders`: `OrderReferenceNumber, Timestamp, OrderLine, ItemNumber, Quantity`

Fields for `broken`: `OrderReferenceNumber, OrderLine, Timestamp`

Corresponding Java classes were generated by running

```
mvn clean package
```

I need to left-join `orders` with `broken` and include the following fields in the output: `OrderReferenceNumber, Timestamp, BrokenSaleTimestamp, OrderLine, ItemNumber, Quantity`

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare variables
    final Map<String, String> avroSerdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

    // Add Kafka Streams Properties
    Properties streamsProperties = new Properties();
    streamsProperties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "orderProcessor");
    streamsProperties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    streamsProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    streamsProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    streamsProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
    streamsProperties.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "localhost:8081");

    // Specify Kafka Topic Names
    String orderTopic = "com.ecomapp.input.OrderExecuted";
    String brokenTopic = "com.ecomapp.input.BrokenSale";

    // Specify Serializer-Deserializer or Serdes for each Message Type
    Serdes.StringSerde stringSerde = new Serdes.StringSerde();
    Serdes.LongSerde longSerde = new Serdes.LongSerde();
    // For the Order Executed Message
    SpecificAvroSerde<OrderExecuted> ordersSpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<OrderExecuted>();
    ordersSpecificAvroSerde.configure(avroSerdeConfig, false);
    // For the Broken Sale Message
    SpecificAvroSerde<BrokenSale> brokenSpecificAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<BrokenSale>();
    brokenSpecificAvroSerde.configure(avroSerdeConfig, false);


    StreamsBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

    KStream<String, OrderExecuted> orders = streamBuilder
            .stream(orderTopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, ordersSpecificAvroSerde))
            .selectKey((key, orderExec) -> orderExec.getMatchNumber().toString());
    KStream<String, BrokenSale> broken = streamBuilder
            .stream(brokenTopic, Consumed.with(stringSerde, brokenSpecificAvroSerde))
            .selectKey((key, brokenS) -> brokenS.getMatchNumber().toString());

    KStream<String, JoinOrdersExecutedNonBroken> joinOrdersNonBroken = orders
        .leftJoin(broken,
                (orderExec, brokenS) -> JoinOrdersExecutedNonBroken.newBuilder()
                        .setOrderReferenceNumber((Long) orderExec.get("OrderReferenceNumber"))
                        .setTimestamp((Long) orderExec.get("Timestamp"))
                        .setBrokenSaleTimestamp((Long) brokenS.get("Timestamp"))
                        .setOrderLine((Long) orderExec.get("OrderLine"))
                        .setItemNumber((String) orderExec.get("ItemNumber"))
                        .setQuantity((Long) orderExec.get("Quantity"))
                        .build(),
                JoinWindows.of(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(1))
                Joined.with(stringSerde, ordersSpecificAvroSerde, brokenSpecificAvroSerde))
        .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("key = " + key + ", value = " + value));


    KafkaStreams orderStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamBuilder.build(), streamsProperties);
    orderStreams.start();

    // print the topology
    System.out.println(orderStreams.localThreadsMetadata());

    // shutdown hook to correctly close the streams application
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(orderStreams::close));

}
```

When I run this, I get the following maven compile error:

```
[ERROR] /Tech/Projects/jCom/src/main/java/com/ecomapp/kafka/orderProcessor.java:[96,26] incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) VO,VR,K,V,VO
    (argument mismatch; org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Joined<K,V,com.ecomapp.input.BrokenSale> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Joined<java.lang.String,com.ecomapp.OrderExecuted,com.ecomapp.input.BrokenSale>)
```

The issue really is in defining my `ValueJoiner`. The Confluent documentation is not very clear on how to do this when Avro schemas are involved (I can't find examples either). What is the right way to define this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Java cannot resolve the type.

Try:

```java
Joined.<String,OrderExecuted,BrokenSale>with(stringSerde, ordersSpecificAvroSerde, brokenSpecificAvroSerde))
```

To specify the types explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a value joiner variable outside the join function and use it in your join function.

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).